# How do I retrieve assets from a Google Storage bucket within a Google Container Registry automated build?

Tags: google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I've created a mirrored GitHub repo in Google's Container Registry and then created a Build Trigger. The dockerfile in the repo includes `gsutil -m rsync -r gs://asset-bucket/ local-dir/` so that I can move shared private assets into the container.
But I get an error:

```
ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to asset-bucket
```

I have an automatically created service account (@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com) for building and it has the Cloud Container Builder role. I tried adding Storage Object Viewer, but I still get the error.

Shouldn't the container builder automatically have the appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil` build step to do this? That should use default credentials properly and it should Just Work.

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: [ "-m", "rsync", "gs://asset-bucket/", "local-dir/" ]
```

Alternatively, you could try the [GCS Fetcher](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcs-fetcher).

Comment: I'm not currently using a Container Builder build configuration file. I'm only using a Dockerfile. Is that required? I'll work on converting my Dockerfile to YAML...

Comment: No, a `gsutil` call inside a `Dockerfile` won't work. Instead, make a first buildstep like I show above (or with the GCS Fetcher) and then a second step that does a `docker build`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be specific about the answer from @david-bendory, privileged calls cannot occur inside a dockerfile. I created a `cloudbuild.yaml` that looks like this:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: [ "-m", "rsync", "-r", "gs://my-assets/", "." ]
  dir: "static"
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/project-name', '.']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/project-name']
```

and a `dockerfile` that includes

```
COPY static/* www/
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similiar and pull in a repo from Google Cloud Source during my automated build. Do I need to follow the same steps? Also, do I need to build a `cloudbuild.yaml` file to accompany by `Dockerfile`?